# Start Recording an Audio Stream at a specific time for a specific duration from command line

Tags: linux, command-line, audio, streaming, audio-recording

There is a radio station I listen to which plays some remixed dance music songs at a specific time each day however I am not always able to tune in everyday at those times to listen, however I quite enjoy them and want to listen to them later. There is a stream online from the station, and I'm wondering if is possible to start an audio recording at a specific time everyday for a specific length of time?

For my particular case I am referring to the following stream:
http://player.evanovradio.com/CIDCFM/

Is it possible to start recording at 5pm for an hour (so it would stop recording at 6pm) ?

I'm looking to do this from the command line on a linux based machine (on my server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers I was getting was not the complete answers I was looking for, so here is the solution I used:

I found the streaming URL which used RTMP. I created a script that would be run via cronjob to start at 5pm and kill at 6pm. Here is the script I made:

```
#!/bin/sh
rtmpdump -r "rtmp://w1-ovh.evanovradio.com/live" --playpath "CIDCFM" -o /home/jhvisser/Music/driveAt5_$(date +%y%m%d).mp3
```

I used the following crontabs:

```
00 17 * * 1-5 /home/jhvisser/bin/drive-at-five-record
00 18 * * 1-5 pkill rtmpdump
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

[Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) should be exactly, what you are looking for.

**Update 2**

You can use [streamripper](http://streamripper.sourceforge.net/) in combination with cron.

```
$ sudo apt-get install streamripper
```

And to download a stream:

`$ streamripper <url>`

This will save the stream into a .mp3 file.

To stop the download of the stream, you can also use a cron-job and use the streamripper-command:

```
pkill streamripper
```

Comment: But this does not help with how I should be running it at a specific time. I'm sure I could have found out how to record from command line, but I want to record from a specific stream and at a specific time and  duration.

Comment: Have a look at [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). It should be exactly the right tool for you.

Comment: Oh wow, I completely overlooked using Cron. For me to accept your answer you will have to complete it :/.

Comment: @Fogest Done. Sorry, I also completely forgot that at first. :)

Comment: Okay great. One last thing. How do I use this with a audio stream? I gave the stream link in the question as a sample if you need to see what I mean.

Comment: @Fogest You can use [streamripper](http://streamripper.sourceforge.net/)

`$ sudo apt-get install streamripper`
And to download a stream:
`$ streamripper <url>`
This will save each stream into a .mp3 file.

Comment: So now you are no longer suggesting sound-recorder? Can you please read my question here.

Comment: @Fogest Oh, I'm really sorry. I was just looking at the streamripper right now and forgot my previous answer. I've edited my answer. Now it should be correct. :)

Comment: And the stream is not a shoutcast stream so streamripper does not seem to be working (http://player.evanovradio.com/CIDCFM/)

Comment: What type is the stream? streamripper can actually download many different types of streams.(LastFM, Peercast, Live365, Winamp 2) Have a look at the FAQ.

Comment: The stream is flashed based. By looking at the source code of the page I can't seem to determine the URL that the flash player is loading.

Comment: Using the wowza online rtmp player I was able to play the following url: rtmp://w1-ovh.evanovradio.com/live and a stream name of CIDCFM. However I don't know how to use this info to get a stream url that works for streamripper

Comment: Have a look at the [rtmpdump/rtmpsrv/rtmpsuck](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/) project. I will update my answer, if this will answer your question. With this tool you can download streams. I personally do not use it, but it seems to work very well for many other users.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run something on a schedule, cron is the tool. However if it's a one off thing, you want "at":

```
at midnight <<EOF
streamripper http://somesite.com/url/file.blah
EOF
```

or

```
at 1200 friday ...
```

etc